# Morethan one Gridview one Row Databound?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
   protected void gvMeatDispatch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {        
        if (e.Row.Parent.Parent.ID == "gvMeatDispatch")
        {
            DataTable dtpartyname = new DataTable();
            objRetailPL.status = 4;
            dtpartyname = objRetailBAL.GetType(objRetailPL);

            DropDownList ddlpn = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlpartyname");
            if (ddlpn != null)
            {
                ddlpn.DataSource = dtpartyname;
                ddlpn.DataTextField = "partyname";
                ddlpn.DataValueField = "sno";
                ddlpn.DataBind();
                ddlpn.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
                ddlpn.SelectedIndex = ddlpn.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        }
       if (e.Row.Parent.Parent.ID== "gvRetail")
         {
            DataTable dttypeRT = new DataTable();
            dttypeRT = objRetailBAL.getretailtype();

            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddltype");
            if (ddl != null)
            {
                ddl.DataSource = dttypeRT;
                ddl.DataTextField = "type";
                ddl.DataValueField = "sno";
                ddl.DataBind();
                ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
                ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.Count - 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here "gvMeatDispatch" and "gvRetail" are two gridviews in row databound..my if condition is satisfied but second "gvRetail" is not executed..please help me

Comment: don't you think better to have different rowdatabound event for both gridview, as the code inside is totally different for both grids,

Comment: ok. thank you,finally i taken two RowDataBound Events